# Assessing Model Fit for Cumulative Link Mixed Models (CLMM)

Tags: mixed-model, diagnostic

I have a CLMM model that accounts for repeated measurements within individuals (ID) over time, using mixed effects.

```
clmm1  <- clmm(response ~ time + group + (1|ID), data=DatasetLong)
```

I'm seeking methods to assess the model fit, similar to what's available for `mixed_models()`, such as using the `simulate()` function or DHARMa. However, when attempting to use these methods with CLMM, I encountered the error 'no applicable method for 'simulate' applied to an object of class "clmm"'. So far, I've only been able to generate a plot using `plot(fitted(clmm1)`, `residuals(clmm1))`, but I'm even unclear about the interpretation of the x-axis (Index). Is there any other diagnostic methods for model fit?